# Python loop to write all possible strings that can be formed from some letters

Tags: python, performance

The code below generates a query with the product of possibilities that may vary from 'abc' to 'abc ... z'

```
import itertools
import time

res = itertools.product('abcdefgh', repeat=8)
fileObj = open("txt_abcdefgh.txt","w") 
timestamp1 = time.time()

for i in res:   
    print (i) #this only to check the progress of the process
    fileObj.write(i[0] + i[1] + i[2] + i[3] + i[4] + i[5] + i[6] + i[7] + '\n')

timestamp2 = time.time()
fileObj.write('This took %.2f seconds' % (timestamp2 - timestamp1))
fileObj.close()
```

However, I have an entry of only 8 items and the runtime is unsatisfactory.

```
Input      Time             Possibilities
abc        0.01 seconds     27
abcd       0.29 seconds     256
abcde      4.28 seconds     3,125
abcdef     31.59 seconds    46.656
abcdefg    542.44 seconds   823,543
abcdefgh   4806.84 seconds  16,777,216
```

Is there any other way to better this code, maybe with some other language, or with another programming technique?

Comment: It's not the language, it's file I/O. Reduce I/O, you'll reduce execution time. Consider collecting the results in one step, and writing them all at once to a file as another step.

Answer (score 5):

#### 1. Speeding up the code

Here's the initial measurement:

```
$ python ./cr163578.py
('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a')
('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b')
('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c')
... much output deleted ...
('h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h')
$ tail -1 txt_abcdefgh.txt
This took 122.10 seconds
```

Let's make some improvements:

1. Omit the `print` statement, which generates lots of useless output that is just slowing us down.
2. Use the `with` statement to open and close the file.
3. Omit the time measurement — we can use the `time` program to do the measurement.

Here's version 2:

```
import itertools
with open('txt_abcdefgh.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in itertools.product('abcdefgh', repeat=8):
        f.write(i[0] + i[1] + i[2] + i[3] + i[4] + i[5] + i[6] + i[7] + '\n')
```

This is about 8 times as fast as the original:

```
$ /usr/bin/time python cr163578.py
       16.73 real        16.45 user         0.23 sys
```

Now let's use the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method to build the output instead of lots of `+` operations. Here's version 3:

```
import itertools
with open('txt_abcdefgh.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in itertools.product('abcdefgh', repeat=8):
        f.write(''.join(i) + '\n')
```

This is about 16 times as fast as the original:

```
$ /usr/bin/time python cr163578.py
        8.25 real         8.01 user         0.21 sys
```

And finally, let's avoid the need to append the newline to each line of output by using the [`writelines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) method of the file. Here's version 4:

```
import itertools
with open('txt_abcdefgh.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(map(''.join, itertools.product('abcdefgh', repeat=8)))
```

This is about 20 times as fast as the original:

```
$ /usr/bin/time python cr163578.py
        5.87 real         5.73 user         0.12 sys
```

#### 2. Runtime complexity

If there are \$k\$ letters in your alphabet, and \$n\$ characters in the strings you are constructing, then there are \$k^n\$ strings altogther. Here \$k=8\$ and \$n=8\$ so there are \$8^8 = 16,777,216\$ possibilities, which take \$9 \times 8^8 = 150,994,944\$ bytes to store on disk.

Your aim is to have \$k=26\$ and \$n=26\$. But then there will be $$26^{26} = 6,156,119,580,207,157,310,796,674,288,400,203,776$$ possibilities, which can't possibly be generated or stored.

Whatever you are trying to do, you will have to find some other way to do it.